# Coloured charts - VBA Excel 2007 - data source colours to be reflected within the charts

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have worksheet which contains several bar charts, and the source data for those charts is colour coded and on the same worksheet. 
I have the code below which I was hoping would turn the colours of the bars in the charts the same colours as the source data, but its not working, it just turns all the bars white.  Does anyone have any idea why this code isnt working and matching the colours?  very grateful for any help you may be able to provide.
I'm using excel 2007. thank you.

```
Sub CellColorsToChart()
Dim oChart As ChartObject
Dim MySeries As Series
Dim FormulaSplit As Variant
Dim SourceRange As Range
Dim SourceRangeColor As Long

'Loop through all charts in the active sheet
  For Each oChart In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects

'Loop through all series in the target chart
  For Each MySeries In oChart.Chart.SeriesCollection

    'Get Source Data Range for the target series
   FormulaSplit = Split(MySeries.Formula, ",")

    'Capture the first cell in the source range then trap the color
   Set SourceRange = Range(FormulaSplit(2)).Item(1)
    SourceRangeColor = SourceRange.Interior.Color

    On Error Resume Next

    'Coloring for Excel 2007 and 2010
    MySeries.MarkerBackgroundColor = SourceRangeColor
    MySeries.MarkerForegroundColor = SourceRangeColor
    MySeries.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = SourceRangeColor
    MySeries.Format.Line.BackColor.RGB = SourceRangeColor
    MySeries.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = SourceRangeColor

  Next MySeries
Next oChart

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go inside the chart...

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
For i = 1 To ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points.Count
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Select
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = Range("B" & i).Interior.Color
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
Next
```

Paint with the color of cell B1:B...

Comment: thank you, i'll give this a try and see how i get on, will come back to confirm shortly. much appreciated.

Comment: 'Loop through each column in the range. For cl = 1 To rng.Columns.Count 'Color the points of the series the same colors as the range interior. Let cur_CHART.SeriesCollection(1).Points(cl).Interior.Color = ActiveSheet.Cells(rng.Row, rng.Columns(cl).Column).Interior.Color Next

Comment: sorry for bad formatting above, but this helped to solve my problem. thank you.